# retrieve contour using fillpoly in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am getting a very difficult problem in opencv c++ new platform .
I want to retrive an image mask using fillpoly in opencv 2.4.7 , but I am getting syntax error in every time. please help me i am pasting my code

`vecpt` is a vector of `cv::Point` data type in opencv and it is holding some coordinates location.

Now I want to retrieve a contour mask from user selected marked point location

```
int num = (int)vecpt.size();
        Point *pt4 = new Point[num];
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        {
            pt4->x=vecpt[i].x;
            pt4->y=vecpt[i].y;


        }


        fillPoly(img2,&pt4,&num,1,Scalar(0,255,0),8);
```

I got the following error:

`Error -- No matching function in fillpoly`

I changed all types several times the parameter but it failed every time. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

oh, those pesky pointers ;)

i think, you can get away without any copy:

```
vector<Point> vecpt;
int num = (int)vecpt.size();

const Point * pt4 = &(vecpt[0]); // *@#! const

fillPoly(img2,&pt4,&num,1,Scalar(0,255,0),8);
```